How to set up web server with Perl CGI on Catalina
I've got an old MBP that's maxed out at MacOS 10.15.7 / Catalina, and I'm trying to use it as a web server capable of running Perl CGI scripts. Furthermore, I want to serve pages from ~/Sites; I want to run the scripts with Perl 5.38, which I've installed under my home directory with perlbrew; I want to access the server from another machine on my LAN (i.e., not simply a localhost-only solution).
One complication is that homebrew no longer officially supports Catalina, so I need to avoid trying a homebrew solution, and instead use Catalina-supplied things as much as possible (apart from Perl).
I've managed to find enough instructions for configuring /etc/apache2/* so that pages are served from ~/Sites, and I can access them from a different machine on the LAN. I've also been able to access a Perl script, ~/Sites/hello.pl:
#!/Users/chap/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.38.0/bin/perl
print "<html>";
print "<head>";
print "<title>Hello, World!</title>";
print "</head>";
print "<body>";
print "<h1>Hello, World!</h1>";
my $version = $^V;

print "Perl version: $version\n";
print "</body>";
print "</html>";

The output, when I browse http://retsina.local/hello.pl, is:
Hello, World!
Perl version: v5.18.4

So clearly the shebang line isn't being read, and I need to tell Apache to execute perl from a different location.
Also, once I have that working, I expect there will be a lot more gotchas when I try to execute the real Perl script, which I've developed and tested in my own home directory while logged into my shell, with my own ENV, etc.
Can someone provide some guidance here? I apologize for the lack of specificity -- this is mostly black magic to me. Glad to provide more details as requested.

Wow... homebrew no longer supports Catalina!? You should try MacPorts, IMO a far better choice anyway.  You can find the macports installer on this page.

I’ve had very good luck using homebrew on systems that no longer get support. Did you try installing the packages you need to validate if they work still?

bmike and @Seamus - thanks, I will see what's involved for each. Do you believe I'll have better luck with the OP, however?

@bmike - I have continued updating/upgrading homebrew on the Catalina system. I do recall hitting a snag installing one package (dont recall), and I'm seeing messages like "Error: undefined method `core_tap?' for nil:NilClass", but mostly still working. Will try installing webserver stuff.

Also, MAMP looks very nice since it has everything you need in a very nice package and no brew needed if you can use a newer perl than you specify. https://www.mamp.info/en/release-notes/mac/ It’s main line package supports macOS 10.12+

Regardless of what package I use, I still need to configure it to do what I need. I've set the document root to ~/Sites, I can access the page non-locally, but I still can't figure out how to specify which Perl to run. Is there any way to make Apache honor the shebang line when launching a script?
